# Where clause in sql command

Tags: java, sql, swing, jdbc

```
String variable_name      =jTextfield.getText();
    *connection establishing code*
        ResultSet oResultSet =statement.executeQuery("Select *
        from table_name
        where comn_name = 'variable_name'
    ");
       if(oResultSet.next()) {
jTextField2.
setText(oResultSet.getString(1).toString());  } 
else
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "invalid");
```

Later on I have to add data which I have retrieved from database in textfield of Netbeans. The problem which I am facing is I am not able to get the row with the variable name I am giving it through keyboard. I am directly entering into else part of loop.

Comment: Edit your question and provide (1) sample data; (2) desired results; (3) the results you are getting that are not correct; (4) a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: Check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1g3Dpp6D-TY prepared statements http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html#supply_values_ps Swing layouts https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html Ω

Answer (score -1):

It depends what you use to execute the SQL command. For example, ODBC interfaces use `?` in the SQL string to indicate that a parameter will be supplied at execution time. The MSSQL interface allows defining functions with typed parameters, with names like `@myarg`. More specific context would help.

Comment: How do we indicate that parameter will be supplied at execution time.